# .Obj Wavefront uv coordindates to sphere xyz coordinates c#

Tags: c#, .obj

I would like to ask if it is possible convert uv coordinates to XYZ values?

I have an obj file that follows the syntax:

```
v 0.888145 -0.014144 -0.325690
vt 0.499900 0.002093
v 0.887647 -0.049252 -0.284089
vt 0.227537 0.010715
v 0.886307 -0.065420 -0.325383
vt 0.097842 0.010796
v 0.881293 -0.094837 -0.285221
vt 0.176470 0.016385
...
```

The vertex v values are not needed for me, but vt values I need to convert to spherical coordinates.
Is there any reference to math behind how UV values could be mapped to Unit Sphere mesh vertices as XYZ?

Comment: The v values are x,y,z.  The vt are textures.  See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file

Comment: I knot that they are textures. But I need to convert them to spherical coordinates

Comment: The textures are values between zero and one and are not coordinates.   It is a roughness of the surface.